# Finding Shortest Paths of weighted graph using stacks

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I will be given some kind of this graph as in the picture below. I've searched some algorithms but it seams as if it is something impossible for me to figure them out. In fact using [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) it is kinda of possible, but unfortunately I'm only allowed to use stacks (instead of matrices). I also looked for [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but I could not get the relationship with my problem.[image: picture]

Clearly my aim is to get all **shortest paths** from one point to another one. As I mentioned I will just output the solution from my **stack** in a vector string. I guess I have to visit each node and what I am most afraid is of getting stacked in a loop or even loosing the track during the search.
Also note that this is **not a directed graph**. If  Dijkstra's algorithm is applicable here I would be very grateful if anyone of you would guide me and I would really appreciate any help, suggestion, idea or even a vision for not getting stacked in a loop or loosing the track while searching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are the edges unweighted?

Comment: No. They are weighted

Comment: If the edge weights are positive, you can implement the Dijkstra's algorithm in O(n^2) using just a couple of auxiliary arrays to store shortest path length, previous node on the path from the start and a bool array to mark nodes with already know shortest path.  I see no use of any stacks.

Comment: If we assumed that the shortest path from P to F :  "PKCBICF" we'd use stack to push or pop node's name. And if we'd use a bool array to mark nodes, we can see that node "C" is visited two times already.  // Node "C" is the biggest one in figure, it is hardly seen

Comment: OK, I misread. So, you need ALL shortest paths. Are the edges weighted or unweighted - the title of the question contradicts with your comment.

Comment: The shortest path is only one. Are you looking for the shortest k paths or for all the paths shorter than a given length?

Comment: @BlackBear it is true that the shortest path is only one. But it is not unique. What I mean is that if the shortest path has N steps to reach there might be different paths which have again N steps to reach.  which means I need all these paths.(with N steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have values of all shortest paths from some chosen node to all other nodes you will be fine with Dijkstra algorithm -- it is basically augmented BFS. Once you get the idea behind BFS you should not have any problems with understanding Dijkstra. Actually it is much easier to implement BFS with a single `queue` than with `arrays`.
Is it some formal (school?) requirement that you have to use `stacks`. If so it is rather strange... But you can still emulate -- in totally inefficient way -- a `queue` with two `stacks`.

(btw. DFS uses stack)

If you want to have all all shortest paths from all nodes to all other nodes, you can just run Dijkstra from each node or you can try Bellman-Ford which is bit faster, but a little bit harder to grasp.

If you want just a shortest path from a single node to some other node, (bit augmented) bidirectional BFS will be the best choice.

If you have Silverlight plugin, you can try this little application in 50% written by me:
http://grzesiaka.home.pl/GraphTutor/ you will find there a presentation step-by-step of algorithms you are interested in (with data structures and pseudo-code). Hopefully it helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to use Dijkstra algorithm, but I'm a little bit confused for keeping track of visited nodes and mostly for not getting into an infinite loop

Comment: You have just keep track of visited nodes -- may be bit tricky if you are only allowed to use stacks, but still doable. Look at the pseudo-code of BFS (in case you have got silverlight). Btw: I would first to try to solve the problem normally (without any restriction) and would try to meet these strange requirements.